# PHP: how to fill an array with keys and values so 1 = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 3 etc

Tags: php, arrays

I am looking to do something like (psuedo_code)

```
$myarray = fill_array_keys_and_values_from_parameter1_until_parameter2(18, 50);
```

So that I get

```
$myarray= array(

'18' => '18',
'19' => '19',
...
'50' => '50'
)
```

without having to a for loop ideally. Is there such a PHP function, I had a browse of the manual but could not see what I was looking for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use a for loop? And why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific function that can do this (although there are a couple that come close.)

What about doing this?

```
$values = range(18, 50);
$array = array_combine($values, $values);
```

Comment: +1 This is pretty much the best way. Note that if you want the values as strings, as in the question, you would have to run `array_map()` over the range to convert to string.

Answer (score 4):

Using a for loop:

```
$arr = array();
foreach (range(18, 50) as $i) {
    $arr[$i] = $i;
}
```

simshaun's solution is much better, though.

Comment: This is not a for loop and is inefficient in terms of memory, this is a real for loop `for($i = 18; $i <= 50; ++$i) {
    $arr[$i] = $i;
}`